# How to apply the definition of line integral when we have a vector field in spherical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, line-integrals

Here is the definition of line integral as it appears in Apostol's *Calculus*, Volume II

> Let $\pmb{\alpha}$ be a piecewise smooth path in n-space defined on an
> interval $[a,b]$, and let $\pmb{f}$ be a vector field defined and
> bounded on the graph of $\pmb{\alpha}$. The line integral of $\pmb{f}$
> along $\pmb{\alpha}$ is denoted by the symbol $\int\pmb{f}\cdot
>  d\pmb{\alpha}$ and is defined by the equation
>
> $$\int_a^b\pmb{f}[\pmb{\alpha}(t)]\cdot\pmb{\alpha}'(t)dt$$
>
> whenever the integral on the right exists, either as a proper or
> improper integral.

Consider the following path $\pmb{\alpha}$ in 3-space

$$\pmb{\alpha}(\theta)=R(\sin{\theta}\hat{i}+\cos{\theta}\hat{k}), \theta\in [0,\pi]\tag{1}$$

and a vector field

$$\pmb{f}(r,\theta,\phi)=r^2(\cos{\theta}\hat{r}+\cos{\phi}\hat{\theta}-\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}\hat{\phi})\tag{2}$$

We see that $\pmb{\alpha}$ is a function of one parameter $\theta$, and the righthand side expression in (1) gives a linear combination of the standard basis vectors. This coincides with Cartesian coordinates.

$\pmb{f}$ is a function of the three spherical coordinates, and (2) gives a linear combination of the spherical coordinate vectors.

Now, we can convert between standard basis vectors and spherical coordinate vectors, so we can have both $\pmb{\alpha}$ and $\pmb{f}$ in terms of either the standard basis vectors or the spherical coordinate vectors.

**My question is** how do $\pmb{\alpha}$ and $\pmb{f}$ fit into the definition of line integral. That is what is the line integral of $\pmb{f}$ along $\pmb{\alpha}$?

More specifically, what is $\pmb{f}[\pmb{\alpha}(\theta)]$ in this example?

After all, $\pmb{\alpha}$ is in Cartesian in (1) and $\pmb{f}$ takes spherical in (2).

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is defined in terms of the spherical coordinates it is best to translate the expression of $\alpha(\theta)$ into spherical coordinates so that you can easily compute $f$ at $\alpha(\theta).$ Alternatively you could express $f$ into cartesian coordinates and leave $\alpha$ as is but this would be a bad idea. Indeed the curve $\alpha$ is a circular arc. The choice of using spherical coordinates is more appropriate for this problem.

The path $\alpha$ is a circular arc $$ (R \sin \theta,0,R \cos \theta) : \theta \in [0,\pi]$$
Recall that the spherical coordinates are given by

\begin{aligned}x&=r\sin \theta \,\cos \phi ,\\y&=r\sin \theta \,\sin \phi ,\\z&=r\cos \theta .\end{aligned}

So the path $\alpha$ can be described in spherical coordinates as the place where the radius $r$ and the angle $\phi$ are constant with $r = R$ and $\phi = 0$.

From this we deduce two facts :

- $\alpha'(\theta) = \frac{d \alpha}{d \theta} = R \hat \theta.$
- The restriction of $f$ to the curve $\alpha$ is $$f(R,\theta,0) = R^2 \cos \theta \hat r + R^2 \hat \theta$$

It follows that

$$ \int_0^\pi f(\alpha (\theta)) \cdot\alpha'(\theta) d\theta = \int_0^\pi R^2 \cos \theta \;(\hat r \cdot R\hat \theta)  + R^2 \; (\hat \theta \cdot R\hat \theta) \; d\theta$$
Now use the fact the the vectors $\hat r, \hat \phi , \hat \theta$ are orthonormal this last integral can be reduced to

$$ \int_0^\pi R^3 d\theta = \pi R^3.$$

Comment: This all makes sense but the thing that still confuses me is that in the definition we have $\pmb{f}(\pmb{\alpha}(t))$. But in our example, we have a function $\pmb{f}(r,\theta,\phi)$, a function $\pmb{\alpha}(\theta)$, and the expressions $r=R$, $\phi=0$. Does the expression $\pmb{f}(\pmb{\alpha}(\theta))$ mean anything in this example? You seem to say that $\pmb{f}(\pmb{\alpha}(\theta))=f(R,\theta,0)$. I can see, intuitively, why this is what we want (ie $\pmb{f}$ along $\pmb{\alpha}$, but I can't see it in terms of the mathematical notation used.

Comment: Somehow I am expecting $\pmb{\alpha}$ to be a vector $\langle r, \theta, \phi \rangle$ so that it can be passed to $\pmb{f}$ which accepts this vector as argument.

Comment: Can we say (1) is an incomplete description of the path? We need to specify that $\phi=0$ and $r=R$ and $\theta$ is in $[0,\pi]$. These are the spherical coordinates. (2) simply says that $\pmb{\alpha}(r,\theta,\phi)=\pmb{\alpha}(R,\theta,0)=r\hat{r}=R\hat{r}=R\sin{\theta}\hat{i}+R\cos{\theta}\hat{j}$. You see my doubt? $\pmb{f}(\pmb{\alpha}(\theta))$ seems to require that $\pmb{\alpha}$ be the same vector that $\pmb{f}$ is a function of. But it isn't quite it seems. We have to rather realize that both $\pmb{f}$ and $\pmb{\alpha}$ are functions of $r, \theta$, and $\phi$, and $\pmb{\alpha}$

Comment: restricts the range of these variables for both $\pmb{f}$ and $\pmb{\alpha}$. It just doesn't quite seem to fit into the definition of line integral.

Comment: It's an abuse of notation. A vector field is an assigning of a vector to each point in your space. When you write $f(r,\theta,\phi) = ...$ instead of seeing $f$ as function from $\mathbb R \times [0,\pi] \times[0,2\pi]$ to vectors you should rather understand it as a function from $3D-space$ to vectors. I'll post another comment later to address your other points but I have to go now.

Comment: No, we cannot say that that $(1)$ is an incomplete description of the path. The map $\theta \mapsto \alpha(\theta)$ is fully defined. It is only if we wanted to describe the curve  in terms of spherical coordinates that you the curve is defined by $\phi = 0$ and $r = R$.